# Is there a way that I can embed a barcode scanner in an Ionic 2 app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

All the phonegap plugins I have found so far for scanning barcode seems to pop out the native default camera view that takes the whole screen size. What I need is to embed the camera view inside an existing screen (html page) of the Ionic2 app.
Can someone please advise me of what I should do.

I tried on this : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner